# JSP pages are being displayed as a blank screen after Upgrading SpringBoot to 2.6.8+ version

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

After Upgrading SpringBoot to 2.6.8+ version, JSP pages are being displayed as a blank screen, Is JSP support removed from SpringBoot 2.6.8+ onwards?

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency into pom.xml :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for reverting back, but tomcat-embed-jasper dependency is already added to the pom and since I am not using the JSTL tags I think jstl dependency will not be needed, jsp pages used to load properly until SpringBoot 2.6.7  but after upgrading to SpringBoot 2.6.8 I am seeing this issue where jsp page is displayed as a blank screen , do you think there might be any another reason?